# Unable to mock method using pytest-mock

Tags: pytest, pytest-mock

I have a class 'MyClass' with code as below.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(update_type_id='1')
        
        self.update_type_id = update_type_id
        self._cursor = <database_connection).cursor()

    def update_start_dt(self):
        self._update_job_ctrl_start_dt()
        
    def _update_job_ctrl_start_dt(self):
        update_sql, v_1  = self._get_update_sql(self._update_type_id)
        logger.debug(f'Update sql: {update_sql} and v_1: {v_1}')
                
    def _get_update_sql(self, update_type_id: int) -> Tuple:
        sql = f"SELECT start_sql, end_sql FROM <database.table> where update_type_key = {self._update_type_id}"
        self._run_sql(sql)
        record = self._cursor.fetchone()
        if record:
            return record
        else:
            logger.error(f'Record Not Found. Update type key ({update_type_id}) not found in the table in the database')
            raise Exception


    def _run_sql(self, sql_statement: str):
        try:
            self._cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        except (Exception, Error) as e:
            logger.error(f'Error {e} encountered when reading from table')
            raise e
```

I am trying to write a test function using pytest-mock which will test the update_start_dt method. The method internally invokes a series of private methods and I am having difficulty in mocking the code which runs through all the private methods. Can anyone help me to understand in what all ways we can mock?

I tried to refer multiple online websites but couldn't get a complete picture.

```
class TestMyClass:
    
    def test_update_start_dt(mocker,mock_get_connection,mock_run_sql):
    
        mock_manager = mocker.Mock()
        mock_get_update_sql = mock_manager.patch('MyClass._get_update_sql')
        mock_get_update_sql.return_value = ('123','234')
        myclass = MyClass(update_type_id='1')
        
        myclass.update_start_dt()
```

I am getting error as below for above test code

```
update_sql, v_1  = self._get_update_sql(self._update_type_id)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are patching on a `Mock` object that you are creating, for the purposes of your test you do not need to explicitly create a `Mock` object. Shown below is how you would test it instead, where we `patch` directly on the class.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, update_type_id='1'):
        
        self._update_type_id = update_type_id
        self._cursor = None

    def update_start_dt(self):
        self._update_job_ctrl_start_dt()
        
    def _update_job_ctrl_start_dt(self):
        update_sql, v_1  = self._get_update_sql(self._update_type_id)
        logger.debug(f'Update sql: {update_sql} and v_1: {v_1}')
                
    def _get_update_sql(self, update_type_id: int):
        sql = f"SELECT start_sql, end_sql FROM <database.table> where update_type_key = {self._update_type_id}"
        self._run_sql(sql)
        record = self._cursor.fetchone()
        if record:
            return record
        else:
            logger.error(f'Record Not Found. Update type key ({update_type_id}) not found in the table in the database')
            raise Exception


    def _run_sql(self, sql_statement: str):
        try:
            self._cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        except (Exception, Error) as e:
            logger.error(f'Error {e} encountered when reading from table')
            raise e



def test_update_start_dt(mocker):
    mock_get_update_sql = mocker.patch.object(MyClass, "_get_update_sql")
    mock_get_update_sql.return_value = ("123", "234")
    myclass = MyClass(update_type_id='1')

    myclass.update_start_dt()
```

---

```
=========================================== test session starts ============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: mock-3.7.0
collected 1 item                                                                                           

test_script.py .                                                                                     [100%]

======================================= 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.01s =======================================
```

---

Your code would work if you called the `Mock` object you created instead of the class. That is shown below.

```
def test_update_start_dt(mocker):
    mock_manager = mocker.Mock()
    mock_get_update_sql = mock_manager.patch('MyClass._get_update_sql')
    mock_get_update_sql.return_value = ('123','234')
    # Notice how we use `mock_manager` instead of MyClass
    # tests will now pass
    myclass = mock_manager(update_type_id='1')
    
    myclass.update_start_dt()
```

Hopefully you see what the issue is now.